# AMD Card not detected

Tags: graphics, hp, amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, amdgpu

I am having a hp 15bs laptop, having **AMD Radeon 500** as a graphics card, Windows 10 does detect it, however, Ubuntu doesn't.

Any solution or clue?

Comment: So it doesn't show in the output of `lspci` on the command line?

Comment: not sure about lspci, i need a week to get back to my laptop